# Raster or RGB data cube plotting with lattice package

Tags: r, plot, lattice, levelplot

Suppose I have this very simple 2x2 RGB datacube that I want to plot:

```
set.seed(2017)
dc <- array(runif(12), dim = c(2,2,3))
```

I can plot this just by rasterizing the datacube:

```
plot(as.raster(dc), interpolate = FALSE)
```

[image]

But I would like to plot this data cube with the `lattice` package (for uniformity sake since I am mainly using it for other plotting too).

*Is this possible?* I am looking at `levelplot`, but am not able to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this turned out to be quite an endeavor with `levelplot`.

I convert the RGB hex color values from raster to integers, and then use these values to map them to the color palette of the raster.

```
set.seed(2017)
dc <- array(runif(12), dim = c(2,2,3))
plot(as.raster(dc), interpolate = FALSE)

# convert color hexadecimals to integers
rgbInt <- apply(as.raster(dc), MARGIN = c(1,2), 
             FUN = function(str){strtoi(substring(str, 2), base = 16)})

rgbIntUnq <- unique(as.vector(rgbInt))

lattice::levelplot(x = t(rgbInt), # turn so rows become columns
                   at = c(0,rgbIntUnq),
                   col.regions = sprintf("#%06X", rgbIntUnq[order(rgbIntUnq)]), # to hex
                   ylim = c(nrow(rgbInt) + 0.5, 1 - 0.5), # plot from top to bottom
                   xlab = '', ylab = '')
```

[image]

The legend can also be removed with `colorkey = FALSE` property.

I wonder whether there are simpler ways to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that lattice needs a matrix, that is a numeric matrix, and rasters of RGB become a factor matrix:

```
r <-as.raster(dc)
r
```

gives this result:

```
     [,1]      [,2]     
[1,] "#ECC478" "#780AAC"
[2,] "#89C546" "#4A6F01"
```

to use it as lattice you need to transform this into a numeric matrix, this looks long but it seems is the only way to ensure to keep the order:

```
m <- matrix(as.numeric(as.factor(as.vector(as.matrix(r)))), ncol= 2)

levelplot(m, panel = panel.levelplot.raster)
```

[image]

The problem you will get here is that you won't keep the same RGB colors, but it's a lattice solution.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately keeping the RGB colors was the whole point of my question and problem :(. Somehow using a different color palette would probably do the trick, but I haven't been able to do it. For example, converting the raster hexadecimals to integer colors and using the appropriate color palette.

Comment: Sorry about it, I have an Idea, I will try to implement it

Comment: You can set the correct color in `levelplot` with this option: `col.regions=as.raster(dc)`. The problem is to correctly map the color of `dc` to the color space.